# loop in ruby not working, pulling exif meta from jpeg

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to get this loop working. total noob to ruby.

```
working_dir.each do |x|
        puts x

        puts EXIFR::JPEG.new('/home/alan/workspace/ruby/latlong/#{x}').gps.latitude 
end
```

I get

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/alan/workspace/ruby/latlong/#{x} (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I am hard coding the path. please help. I am trying to pull exif meta data out of a directory of jpegs.

Comment: you should use " " not ' ', theres not string interpolation when you use ' '

Comment: still learning the difference between ' and ". thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you are hitting the error due to lack of string interpolation in single quoted strings. Try switching the single quotes to double:

```
working_dir.each do |x|
  puts EXIFR::JPEG.new("/home/alan/workspace/ruby/latlong/#{x}").gps.latitude
end
```

Note:

1. Though this is posted to pin point the error; follow [@CuriousMind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367985/curiousmind)'s answer, it might have better implementation that what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, it was string interpolation. changing from ' to " made it work.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
folder_which_contains_jpegs = 'workspace/ruby/latlong'
folder_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, folder_which_contains_jpegs) # assume your current dir is `/home/alan`
unless File.directory?(folder_path)
  fail "Error: the directory #{folder_path} doesn't exist"
end

def jpeg_file_list(path, &block)
  Dir.glob(path + '/**/*.jpeg').each(&block)
end

jpeg_file_list do |image_path|
  puts image_path
  puts EXIFR::JPEG.new.image_path.gps.latitude
end
```

will something like this would work?